# If $f(x) = 2^x-4^x+6^x-8^x-9^x+12^x.$ Then Range of $f(x)$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = 2^x-4^x+6^x-8^x-9^x+12^x\;,$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Then Range of $f(x)$ is

$\bf{My\; Trial::}$ Let $2^x = a$ and $3^x=b$, where $a,b>0\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and Let $f(x)=y$

So $y=a-a^2+ab-a^3-b^2+a^2b = -b^2+b(a^2+a)-(a^3+a^2-a)$

So $b^2-b(a^2+a)+(a^3+a^2-a-y) = 0$

Now If given equation has real Roots, Then $\bf{D(Discriminant\;\geq 0)}$

So $(a^2+a)^2-4(a^3+a^2-a-y)\geq 0$

Now I did not understand How can I solve after that

Help me

thanks

Comment: $f(x)\rightarrow+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$. Moreover $f(x)$ is continuous. So if you determine the minimum of value $f(x)$ to be $f_\text{min}$, the range is $[f_\text{min},+\infty)$. So the question reduces to finding the minimum value $f_\text{min}$.

Comment: To Help , How Can I find Minimum value of $f(x),$ If it is possible To calculate Minimum Using Inequality, If Yes Then How can I calculate it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

care about f(0)=0

and f(1)=2-4+6-8-9+12=-1

if you find f'(x)=0 roots or root , you will find maximum and minimum , then check f(-infinity) , f(+infinity) , f'=0 roots

in this case

f'=0 ---> x=-1

y belongs to [-1,+∞)